# Get key from out_of_range exception

Tags: c++, stdmap

I'm using an std::map with strings as keys which are added to the map automatically. When accessing the map with dynamically created keys, it might happen that the key-value pair does not exist and I'd like to know for which keys that is the case.

I thought I could get the wanted functionality by catching the out_of_range exception (oor). However, or.what() only tells me that the key is not found, but not for which key the lookup failed.

Thus my question: can the functionality I am looking for be achieved with the the standard stl tools?

Many thanks
Philipp

Comment: Use only your own access functions to the map. In each access function you know the relevant key. Translate the exception.

Comment: `std::map` has a member function named `find`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like

```
sometype_t::iterator it;
if((it=mymap.find(keystring)) != mymap.end())
{
   // key found
}
else
{
   // key not available
}
```